# Firestore Failed to get document because the client is offline error

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, xamarin.forms

This usually happens when the application goes to OnSleep and then OnResume or it has not been opened for a long time. I think Firestore thinks there is no connection but there is. I don't know how to fix this. What I don't understand is why it looks at the cache when there is an internet connection.

It says the client is offline, but then it writes to a document in my firestore database, I don't understand this.

When resuming the application should we call EnableNetworkAsync? Wait a few seconds for Firestore to connect?

The funny thing about everything is that if I go back into the same part of the application where it gave that exception then it works fine.

more info:
https://github.com/f-miyu/Plugin.CloudFirestore/issues/96

Comment: You could try to request some data before offline, then go offline, and then request the same data and get the same response like you are online. The issue reported before would be helpful. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/3207

Comment: I am online at all times. I don't understand, so it's a firebase bug? Should the Xamarin SDK or the Library I'm using be updated?

Comment: I used my code to check the OnSleep and OnResume. But do not get the offline error (I am online all the times). Maybe
 you could check offline sample code. It could use the database offline. https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet/blob/e7e628af78fd9f1655762911890766d048a3bf46/samples/XamarinForms/XamarinForms/Services/FirebaseOfflineDataStore.cs

Comment: It is an error that occurs randomly, you should have the application on your phone for a few days and test. I have multiple records in the log in production.

Comment: I'm not very familiar on how to use Firebase on Android, however if I understood correctly it seems like the connection is sporadically failing after being idle for some time. As I understand it you are not interested in using data in cache. If this is the case your issue should be fixed by implementing a retry policy (ideally with exponential backoff retries). Please let me know if this approach would be useful for you. This [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/retries#best_practices) might be useful, although the examples use JS.  Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: I really don't know why you couldn't get the document that says not online but then writes to the log in Firestore in another collection and document, it's weird right?